# Why are messages.pending increasing in Vert.x?

Tags: vert.x

Increased messages.pending, messages.pending-local in Vert.x.

From 20 o'clock to 02 o'clock on the next day, it was resolved.
Full GC was performed for 1 ~ 2 seconds and messages.pending, messages.pending-local were canceled regardless of the time of Full GC.

I seek advice on what is the cause.

Answer (score 0):

GC has nothing to do with pending messages on the event bus (this is where I assume you have the messages pending). Your receivers of the messages did not have the capacity to handle the amount of the massages that were incoming, hence they were pending. As the time went on and fewer messages were arriving the receivers had time to process them and the pending message number dropped.